# How to define prodataset with a join table

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

How do you actually define a dataset with a join table? Whenever we do this we get the error, `buffer could only have 1 active parent relation`.

```
DEFINE DATASET FOR eOrder, eOrderLine, eProduct
DATA-RELATION r1 for eOrder, eOrderLine
RELATION-FIELDS (OrderID, OrderID)
DATA-RELATIOn r2 for eOrder, eProduct.
RELATION-FIELDS(ProductID, ProductID)
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your syntax is a little off. You don't have a dataset name in there. The syntax is:

```
DEFINE DATASET <DatasetName> FOR...
```

Also, the period at the end of data relation r2 is ending the statement before the relation fields. Here is an example that will work with the Sports database:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE eOrder LIKE Order.
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE eOrderLine LIKE Order-Line.
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE eCustomer LIKE Customer.

DEFINE DATASET dsOrder FOR eOrder, eOrderLine, eCustomer
DATA-RELATION r1 for eOrder, eOrderLine
RELATION-FIELDS (Order-Num, Order-Num)
DATA-RELATION r2 for eOrder, eCustomer
RELATION-FIELDS (Cust-Num, Cust-Num).
```

Comment: I tried this but i still get the same error as above.

Comment: How are the relation fields defined in your temp tables? What version of OpenEdge are you using?

Comment: I have the same relations like you defined them and we are using OpenEdge v11.6.

Comment: I tried my code snippet in OE 10.1 and 11.7 and I don't get any syntax errors. I don't think only 11.6 would have a problem with it.